# Apache Virtual Hosts Wont Resolve

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have followed this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-6

I have a website in /var/www/html. I followed the guide and i have the main site setup as the first virtual host. I can access the website fine so i havnt broken it. I have added the following to the bottom of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to be able to add some prefix domains. m.example.com, forum.example.com etc. To test this i have tried setting up a second virtual host for the same directory but with a different server name. This should link to the same website, but instead i get a page cannot be displayed error with the following "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName m.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>
```

I have set the following 2 variables in the httpd.conf file

```
ServerName www.example.com:80
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Comment: So I should set these with go daddy? Like forum.example.com goes to the main site and then apache does the rest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add DNS records for the new vhosts. This is done wherever your authoritative DNS service for this domain is hosted.

Comment: So I need to make a new cname alias? This this point to the main domain? So host = forum, points to = example.com?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.

Answer (score 1):

DNS is a long term solution, short term for testing you could just add this to your hosts file on the computer where you're running your browser.

Windows: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts (using notepad or something similar running as Administrator)

Linux: /etc/hosts as root

Then add a new line to it

```
[server IP address] m.example.com www.example.com
```

for example

```
127.0.0.1 m.example.com www.example.com
```

Then after saving you should be able to refresh your browser and see the website.

What this will do is basically setup a local "DNS" entry which your browser will use when trying to resolve the domain.